# REGEXP de busca em json não funciona corretamente quando utilizado string com parênteses

Tags: php, regex

Criei uma expressão regular que faz uma pesquisa no JSON pelo nome e valor do campo, mas não funciona corretamente quando o valor buscado contém parênteses, como um DDD por exemplo, então neste caso **a busca ignora os parênteses** e traz todos os resultados que possuam em qualquer lugar o valor pesquisado, (11) por exemplo, e não apenas quando este valor está entre parênteses, tratando-se de um DDD.

Minha expressão regular:

```
$Search = sprintf('\'"%s":"([^"]*)%s([^"]*)"\'', 'telefone', '(11)');
```

Pesquisa:

```
Contatos::whereRaw("contains REGEXP {$Search}")->get();
```

Valores retornados:

(**11**) --954584

(45) --4**11**081

(62) --58**11**07

**Atualização:**
Neste teste estou utilizando preg_match para fazer a busca em uma string que contém o campo telefone, percebam que invés da expressão regular retornar somente o DDD, está retornando o número 5**011** presente no número do telefone, ignorando os parênteses.

```
$DDD = '(011)';
$json = '{"name":"Teste JSON","email":"exemple@teste.com","telefone":"(011) 5011-3344"}';
preg_match(sprintf('\'"telefone":"([^"]*)%s([^"]*)"\'', $DDD), $json, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Resultado:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(28) ""telefone":"(011) 5011-3344""
  [1]=>
  string(7) "(011) 5"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "011"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "-3344"
}
```

O que preciso alterar nesta expressão regular para que estes parênteses não sejam ignorados?

Comment: Não seria melhor fazer parse desse JSON e iterar até encontrar um match?

Comment: Não, conto com mais de 10 mil itens do banco de dados, é inviável, além de que a busca não é o único filtro.

Comment: Estás a ir buscar esses dados à BD? nesse caso não podes extrair essa informação via BD?

Comment: Não, a plataforma trata-se de uma aplicação gerenciadora de leads, estes leads são recebidos via API em JSON de forma extremamente variada, e possui uma listagem a qual o cliente que gerencia, portanto esta minha dúvida é referente a um filtro de buscas.

Comment: Ok. Coloca um pedaço do JSON para termos material para testar. Podes mesmo colocar um exemplo que não funciona no -> https://regex101.com/ , gravar e colocar de novo aqui para vermos também.

Comment: Atualizado, veja que o REGEX deveria está retornando somente o DDD (011), porém está retornando o valor 011 presente no número do telefone, ignorando os parênteses.

Comment: Raphael, nesse exemplo que colocas-te qual é o resultado final que queres obter? ainda não está claro para mim. Queres extrair de um dado JSON o indicativo com ou sem parêntesis? (nesse caso podes usar algo assim: https://regex101.com/r/fU1dV5/1)  ou queres substituir conteudo dentro do JSON?

Comment: Sergio, o que eu preciso é que quando a string a ser pesquisada esteja com parênteses, estes parênteses não sejam ignorados e o resultado seja exatamente a string pesquisada.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23777/discussion-between-sergio-and-raphael-castro).

Comment: Em resumo, o que ocorre atualmente é que quando utilizo uma string com parênteses, (11) por exemplo, estes parenteses estão sendo ignorados e o valor retornado é qualquer um que possua o valor inteiro, como por exemplo "551199", invés de "(11) 9999999".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sua expressão regular passa o 11 como um grupo, para que a expressão regular capture os parênteses você deve escapá-los com uma barra invertida:

```
$Search = sprintf('\'"%s":"([^"]*)%s([^"]*)"\'', 'telefone', '\(11\)');
```

No segundo exemplo você utiliza `(011)` então seria bom adicionar um "0" opcional com `0?`. também existem grupos na sua expressão que não são utilizados `([^"]*)` e esses parênteses podem ser removidos. Ainda, seu delimitador da expressão (`\'`) regular pode causar confusão, sugiro utilizar `/` ou `#`. Dessa forma fica:

```
$Search = sprintf('#"%s":"[^"]*%s[^"]*"#', 'telefone', '\(0?11\)');
```